# Flex layout grow top div to take remaining space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a scenario when I want the top div to take ramaining space when bottom is re-positioned with "bottom" css.

[image]

```css
div#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

div#body {
  position: static;
  border: 2px solid red;
  flex: 1;
}

div#footer {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="body">Body content</div>
  <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

I have a codepen to illustrate the problem:
https://codepen.io/ydubey/pen/MWrWpNp

I want the body (marked by red border) to grow and take the space left by the footed (marked by blue border).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Because you are using position with child element and you make the child element to escape from the coordinates system

Comment: make it `margin-bottom: -15px;` instead position .It will remain in the flow and be 15px lower

Comment: @James That's only `position: absolute;`, `sticky`, and `fixed`: none of which are used in the OP's code. The other values: `relative` and `static`  _do not_ remove elements' boxes from the normal flow - so there isn't any "escaping of the coordinates system" (as you put it) going on.

Comment: @Dai, sorry for the late reply, I do do some test just now. it is not a 
rigorous to say that it escaping of the coordinates system, but for position relative, the element will only leave the space for the child element (height), but will not expand as the child element, for position static, we could not change the position because it can't be affected by left/right.... property, so not working in OP's sitution, but thanks for telling me that and correct me if I am wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `margin` instead of a standard `bottom` value. With `#body` set at `100%`, the browser won't be able to distinguish the flex-grow, if you use the `bottom` value on `#footer`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

div#body {
  position: static;
  border: 2px solid red;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

div#footer {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="body">Body content</div>
  <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you're looking for using CSS calc().

Here's how I refactored your code, hope it helps!

```css
div#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 200px;
}

div#body {
  position: static;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: calc(100% - 50px); /* Subtracting the footer height to the body */
}

div#footer {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="body">Body content</div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```